# How to send an Ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm using this code to send a POST to my node API to generate a PDF, my node console gives me these errors:

```
$('#renderPDF').click(function(){
      var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/generate',
        data: {doc:"<h1>test 123</h1>"},
      });
      request.done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
});
```

> info: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'child.transform')
>   info:  info:   phantomjs://code/shim.js:157 in transform info:
>   phantomjs://code/shim.js:138 in read

When I send a POST (with the Postman tool), the PDF is rendered and everything works.

```
localhost:8080/api/v1/generate?doc=<h1>testing 123</h1>
```

What am I doing wrong on my POST request?

Comment: those tags inside the data probably make some problems..

Comment: the difference between your ajax post and the url you posted is that the URL displays GET params try to turn type from POST to GET

Comment: The problem might actually be with phantomjs ... have you tried testing it by hand with a real browser?  I have had random issues with phantomjs in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need/can achieve it easier with [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

e.g.

```
data = new FormData();
data.append( 'doc', "<h1>test 123</h1>" );

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/generate',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( data ) {
        alert( data );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are sending the `doc` parameter as a POST parameter, when it looks like its a querystring, try:

```
$('#renderPDF').click(function(){
  var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/generate?doc=<h1>testing 123</h1>',
  });
  request.done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Hope it solves your problem.

EDIT: more info on this. You may be sending the request (from postman) as a POST request, but the values sent are not actually POST parameters, they are querystrings ("GET" parameters if you will).